# Нужна веб-страница с показом реквестов, обращенных к ней

Tags: request, xmlhttprequest, веб-служба, httpwebrequest

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь онлайн-сервис, сайт или страницу, которая позволит проверить дошедшие до нее HTTP-реквесты.

Что примерно надо:

- Я посылаю GET или POST с какими-нибудь хедерами и содержимым.
- Страница/сайт/сервис отображает то, что я ей послал (сразу, аяксом, после рефреша - неважно), либо как-то еще реагирует (создает, например, комментарий к картинке).

Зачем такая возня:
Проверочные реквесты посылаю не сам лично со своей формы, а дергаю экшн на недоступном для копания сервере, а уж он отправляет реквест. Соответственно, мне он возвращает только результат в виде уведомления "Реквест отправлен", а вот что именно ушло и что пришло в ответ - неизвестно. Поэтому сервисы, возвращающие что-то, доступное в консоли браузера, не вариант.

Comment: Поднимите локальный сервер Nginx или Apache с логированием, далее с помощью гугла можно собрать простенький скрипт на PHP или питоне, который будет делать ровно то, что вам надо. Там делов даже без знания нужных языков программирования - пара часов, материалов по этим вопросам - полинтернета. А сервисов таких не знаю, потому что использую как раз выше изложенный способ, но в практической части он вам не подойдет, потому что у меня свои сервера в ЦОД на базе FreeBSD, а вам надо скорее всего под Windows.

Comment: Я ж писал - дергаю экшн на недоступном сервере, а уж он шлет реквест. Как он увидит мой локальный сервер?

Comment: В таком случае, я не понял ваш вопрос, прошу меня извинить.

Comment: За что минус-то? :(

Comment: Не от меня, но скорее всего за непонятный вопрос.

Comment: Postman - сервис, позволяющий получать респонсы, классная штука, особенно если апи

Comment: Да, смотрел. Чересчур накручено для разовой задачи, и так и не понял, можно ли смотреть результаты реквестов, пришедших на него с другого сервера, а не напрямую от меня...